# Why in Raspberry Pi 3 ACT blink 2 times then stop & PWR always RED?

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-3, sd-card

**Observation 1 :** When I power on my Pi3 without a Micro SD card (8gb / 16 gb), both PWR & ACT show as RED color. PWR as Dark RED & ACT as Light RED color.

**Observation 2 :** When I insert a micro SD Card & power on, some time ACT bilking With Green, Orange Then Constantly on with RED color. I tried both (8gb & 16 GB card) but no luck.

**Question 1:** Is it SD card issue ?

**Question 2:** Or is it a micro SD card slot problem ?

**Question 3:** Or is it a usb power cable (AC Adaptor **Input:** 100-240V ~ 50/60Hz 0.3A **OutPut -** 5.2V -- 2.0A) problem  ?

**Question 4:** Is it an issue with Raspberry Pi 3 Board ?

**Note:**

**1.** both 8gb & 16gb micro SD card detect well in Windows 10 PC with CARD Reader & also showing required boot files for Raspbian.

**2.** FORMAT the SD card in FAT32 file system.

**3.** Raspbian not booting from SD Card probably Card not detecting.

**4** Two types of SD Card I tested "***Transcend 8GB @4 HC***" & "***Samsung 16GB EVO @10 HC I*** "

**SD Card Bootable Process**

***Option : 1***

1. SDFormatter Full Erase with FORMAT SIZE OPTION ON
2. Win32 Disk Imager to write Raspbian img to sd card.

***Option : 2***

1. MiniTool Partition Wizard Format sd Card to FAT 32 - Primary partition.
2. WinFlashTool to write Raspbian img to sd card with check box "Resize the last Ext2FS partition (3766M) to the end of the storage device using resize 2fs

***Option : 3***

1. Format sd card in windows 10 with Fat 32
2. copy & past boot-able files into sd card.

***Option : 4***

1. Format sd card in windows 10 with Fat 32
2. Unzip then copy & past [NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/) files into sd card.

*** Nothing work

Comment: The "ACT" LED is Green. It cannot show any other colour, so you should update your question with your actual issue. I assume you are using a Pi3 in the "Official" case. This has a rather poor plastic filter over the LEDS, and when the PWR LED is lit the red output shows through both cutouts in the case.

Comment: @Milliways: you are right, 2 RED lights due to Pi3 "Official" case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now ultimately success with [NOOBS & silentinstall](https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/) Without Keyboard & Monitor. Patience is the key here.

**Steps**

**1.** SD CARD : "Samsung 16GB EVO @10 HC I"

**2.** From Windows 10 Laptop (OS Win 10 Pro 64 bit) using SDFormatter Full Erase sd card with FORMAT SIZE OPTION ON.

**3.** Unzip then copy & past [NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/) files into sd card.

**4.** Edit recovery.cmdline file on the SD-Card with silentinstall

**5.** Insert sd card into Pi3, power on, connect Lan / Ethernet cable.

*Then wait..wait..wait. Patience is the key process in this step & also check your ACT LED (Green) blinking time to time, it means Raspbian installing.*

**5.** Install Advanced IP scanner into your PC / laptop to search if you found any device Name: **raspberrypi.mshome.net** (in My case), Manufacture : **Raspberry Pi Foundation** with a valid Mac & IP Address.

**6.** Use PuTTY connect to Raspbian.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling the card has not been written correctly to be bootable.
Please share the steps you took to create a bootable disk.

The green flashing **usually** indicates the disk is detected/recognized but it turning orange or red might indicate it was unable to boot properly. However i have never encountered this before and I could be wrong.

Common mistakes and problems include (I am not saying you did)

- formatting the disk as NTFS and copying over the files over into the disk.
- downloaded image is corrupt / incomplete but was written on the card anyway

Assuming you are have access to a Windows machine, recommend going over the steps listed [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Flashing_the_SD_Card_using_Windows) and checking if any have been skipped or overlooked.

Found some more tips [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)

Comment: Thanks for your information, let me check. The 2 RED light issue solve. So I updated my post.